# how to convert 2d list to 2d native python array not numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list, numpy

I want to convert python 2d list,

```
[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
```

to

python3 `array.array` type,

```
[ [1 2 3]

[4 5 6] ]
```

The most important challenge is I wont import `numpy`. 
So I cant use `np.asarray()`.

I have also used `array.fromlist()` and `array.extend()`. 
Both methods are creating an array of single dimension.
But I want to convert multi dimension list to multi dimension array.
Is there any way?

Comment: I want to convert to  python array module fro python list

Comment: `numpy.ndarray` has attributes like `shape` and `strides` which allow it to represent multidemensional arrays.  Python `array` does not have those.  It also does not implement an `object` (or pointer) type, which would allow it to 'contain' lists or other objects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're asking is not possible.  From [the `array` docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html):

> This module defines an object type which can compactly represent an array of basic values: characters, integers, floating point numbers ...  The type is specified at object creation time by using a type code

The only supported types are as follows (notice the absence of `list`):

```
Type code            C Type        Python Type
    'b'         signed char                int
    'B'       unsigned char                int
    'u'          Py_UNICODE  Unicode character
    'h'        signed short                int
    'H'      unsigned short                int
    'i'          signed int                int
    'I'        unsigned int                int
    'l'         signed long                int
    'L'       unsigned long                int
    'q'    signed long long                int
    'Q'  unsigned long long                int
    'f'               float              float
    'd'              double              float
```

It seems like you might be confusing the `array` module, with a native implementation of `numpy` arrays.  ***This is not the case***.

Comment: yes I have read this. That's why I asked this question. It may be an indescent way to convert to python array. But I want to know a way to convert.

Comment: And as I clearly state in my answer.  **This is not possible**.  You cannot create a native `array` that contains `list`

Comment: What I mean is I dont want to create an **array of list**. I want to create an **array of array** from **list of list**.

Comment: Which is equally **not possible**.  The closest you can get is a `list` of `array`